# Object-c How to animate different set of images in different duration time one after the other (iphone)

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, uiimage, core-animation

i need to animate 10 sets of images ,(10 arrays of images) one after another
each set will animate in different duration.
i tried to do that with UIImageView like this :

```
[myImageView1 setAnimationImages:imagesSet1];
[myImageView1 setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
[myImageView1 setAnimationDuration:2];
[myImageView1 startAnimation];


[myImageView1 setAnimationImages:imagesSet2];
[myImageView1 setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
[myImageView1 setAnimationDuration:5];
[myImageView1 startAnimation];
```

but this not works,it shows the last images.

Comment: because u continuously call Animations ,That is  the Problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballImg1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballImg3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballImg4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballImg5.png"],nil];

 NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballAniImg1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballAniImg3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballAniImg4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballAniImg5.png"],nil];

 NSArray *array3=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballRotImg1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballRotImg3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballRotImg4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballRotImg5.png"],nil];

array4=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:array1,array2,array3,nil];

 i1=0;   
 [self performSelector:@selector(animation1:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] afterDelay:0];
 i=0;



 -(void)animation1:(NSNumber*)k
{
if(i1<[array4 count])
{
int m1=[k floatValue];
NSArray *arr1= [array4 objectAtIndex:i1];
myImageView1.animationImages=arr1;
myImageView1.animationDuration=m1;
myImageView1.animationRepeatCount=1;
[myImageView1 startAnimating];
i1++;
    [self performSelector:@selector(animation1:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] afterDelay:3.0];

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code, Much More Easy, So use it n Enjoy

```
animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 20.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: It never stops. How to stop it? i set repeat count but result did not change.

Comment: @yucelbayram: Please set     [animatedImageView stopAnimating]; When you need stop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use blocks

```
-(void)showImage1 {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                     animations:^{
                                     [myImageView1 setImage:image1];
                                 };
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                       [self showImage2];
                                }];
}

-(void)showImage2 {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                     animations:^{
                                     [myImageView1 setImage:image2];
                                 };
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                       ...
                                }];
}
```

Comment: it's strange that i don't have "UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft" option ?!

Comment: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
A transition that flips a view around its vertical axis from left to right. The left side of the view moves toward the front and right side toward the back.
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared in UIView.h. from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Ok , i used instead "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight" but nothing happends ,

Comment: how i can resolve the issue?, i made exactly as you saied,but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ball%d.png", i]]];
        UIImageView *animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
        animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
        animatedImages.animationDuration = 1.0;
        animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        [animatedImages startAnimating];
        [myview addSubview:animatedImages];  
        [animatedImages release];

     }
```

Comment: but i want to run set of images one after other with different times !?

Comment: If you want to run three images just save the name as ball1.png , ball2.png , ball3.png ... this code will work...

Comment: but how i can change the animatedImages.animationDuration for each animatedImages  group ?

Comment: dont change anything this code... just change the image name.. it will work nicely...